# std_msgs/ColorRGBA[].displaying different color for each point

Tags: ros, rviz, marker, points

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello sir,

I am trying to display different color for each point. I am able to display points with single color using:

```
             draw.color.b = 1.0;
             draw.color.a = 1.0;
```

but in am unable to display points with different colors.
my lines of code is:

```
for(int i =0;i<=5;i++)

{

geometry_msgs::Point p;

     std_msgs::ColorRGBA c;
      p.x =i;
      p.y = 1;
      p.z = 1;
             c.r = 1;
             c.g = 1;
             c.b=1;
      draw.points.push_back(p);
      draw.colors.push_back(c);
}
marker_pub.publish(draw);
```

thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9297/std_msgs/colorrgba%5B%5D.displaying-different-color-for-each-point/) by [closed](https://answers.ros.org/users/242/closed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-03-05

Post score: -2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-05**:
Please update your question to say what you see on the screen and what you expect to see when you render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the code you posted, the color is the same (white) for all the points: r=g=b=1.  Maybe you meant to have something like:
c.r = 0;
c.g = 0;
c.b = float(i)/5;

Which would give you a spread from black to blue.

---

Originally posted by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) with karma: 1351 on 2011-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2